# Display subcategories and its subcategories in dropdown menu

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, submenu, drop-downs

I am making something like [mysmartprice](http://www.mysmartprice.com/) menu in magento, can anybody point me to the resource or search term. I have UI read with me, i just need the correct loop or function to begin. I am familiar with magento theme making, i have made some themes for ecommerce website also, but for this sub-category and its sub-category i am bit confuse.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this using html, css or there is mega menu extension available for this type of functionality. check on ehere http://www.magestore.com/magento-mega-menu-extension.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to display all the categories in a select dropdown, you may have to make some modifications depending on what you need:

```
<select id="category" name="category">
<?php
  $rootCat = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
  $categories = explode(',',Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCat)->getChildren());
  foreach($categories as $cat){ 
     $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $category->getId();?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Thanks for the info. Great Read ! Found https://saverupaya.com/""  target=""_blank""> this site  that compares the prices of latest gadgets, home accessories, fitness accessories and many more across markets at https://saverupaya.com/""  target=""_blank""> Save Rupaya  and you also will be notified about availability of products with price drops.

```
                                    "
```